# Laradock unit testing database errors PDOException

Tags: php, mysql, unit-testing, docker, laradock

So I'm trying to write unit tests for a Laravel application like this:

```
protected function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();
    $this->disableMiddlewareForAllTests();
    $this->withoutExceptionHandling();
}

public function test_login_badRequest()
{
    $response = $this->call('post', '/login');
    $response->assertOk();
    $response->assertJson(['status' => 400]);
}
```

The above works fine, and gives this output:

```
Test 'Tests\Unit\LoginTest::test_login_badRequest' started
Test 'Tests\Unit\LoginTest::test_login_badRequest' ended
Time: 69 ms, Memory: 12.00MB
OK (1 test, 2 assertions)
```

But the next test is another story:

```
public function test_login_goodRequest()
{
    $response = $this->call('post', '/login', [
        'email' => 'email@email.com',
        'password' => 'P4ssw0rd'
    ]);

    $response->assertOk();
    $response->assertJson(['status' => 200]);
}
```

As soon as the test hits this line of code in the application:

```
/* Retrieve User associated with posted email address */
$user = $this->userModel
    ->where('email', $request->post('email'))
    ->get();
die('here');// <-- Happens in browser, does not happen in tests.
```

This is the error:

```
1) Tests\Unit\LoginTest::test_login_goodRequest
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
/var/www/html/projects/laravel-template/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:68 ...
```

I've been banging my head against this one for a few days, any ideas what's going on here, and how to get that die to print in the tests?
Cheers.

-- Laradock, Docker, nginx, mysql,
PHP 7.2.4-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Apr  5 2018 08:53:57) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.4-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies

EDITED:

.env:

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:Z+p6uA3G2DyCCFBXOPgrWwls1U6z/vi8Zi2r4eKHxEY=
APP_DEBUG=true
DEBUGBAR_ENABLED=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=sample_database
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=
MAIL_PASSWORD=
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

Comment: Please post your `docker-compose.yml` and `.env`

Comment: @alex docker-compose.yml is 900 lines of code which part are you interested in and I'll paste it.

Comment: Just make sure that `DB_HOST` in `.env` is the same as the mysql container name. They do not specify `container_name` in their original `docker-compose.yml`, therefore docker could name your containers as `application_mysql` or something. If you run `docker ps`, you will see the container names. Also, make sure PHPUnit uses the same mysql container name when connecting, if it doesn't take the value from `.env`.

Comment: I am 95% sure this is the issue. If it actually helps you, I'll post it as the answer.

Comment: Ok brilliant, docker ps says: CONTAINER ID,IMAGE,COMMAND,CREATED,STATUS,PORTS,NAMES: f10f6deb314a, laradock_mysql, "docker-entrypoint.s…",2 weeks ago, Up 2 hours, 0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, laradock_mysql_1

Comment: I tried changing DB_HOST in .env to 'laradock_mysql' and 'laradock_mysql_1', but the test output is just "PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away" (after 30 second wait).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180573/discussion-between-donal-lynch-msc-and-alex-karshin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the chat we found out you were running the tests from your host. It is possible to run tests from host, you must expose your ports to the host though. I think laradock does that, though I'm not sure if you had it in your setting (the github version does).
Although, it's a docker anti-pattern.

Containers are designed to contain all the communication between them and from host you should only be doing `up` and `down`.

Hence, the best solution is to enter your `workspace` container with `docker exec -it workspace bash` or `docker-compose exec workspace bash` and run tests from there.

Comment: I'm up and running with the tests now (from inside the workspace container). Thanks very much!